# While connecting react with tawk. name and email are getting sent in encoded

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

this is my code in componentDidMount(){}
I am trying to initialize the widget popup on page load and then setting the name and email from the received params from the previous page

```
 const fullName = this.state.data[0];
    console.log(fullName);
    const email = this.state.data[1];
    const hashCode = this.state.data[2];

    if (window.Tawk_API) {
      window.Tawk_API = window.Tawk_API || {};
      window.Tawk_LoadStart = new Date();
      window.Tawk_API.onLoad = function () {
        window.Tawk_API.setAttributes(
          {
            name: `${fullName}`,
            email: `${email}`,
            hash: `${hashCode}`,
          },
          function (error) {}
        );
      };
    }
    const tawk = document.getElementById("tawkId");
    if (tawk) {
      return window.Tawk_API;
    }
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.id = "tawkId";
    script.async = true;
    script.setAttribute("crossorigin", "*");
    script.charset = "UTF-8";
    script.src = "https://embed.tawk.to/{id}/{id}";
    document.head.appendChild(script);

    const s0 = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    if (s0 || s0.parentNode) {
      s0.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can post by element.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).